# ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded - Django request.body

Tags: python, json, django

the `request.body` contains this:

```
"event=project.status.update&project_id=807276&project_status_code=in_progress"
```

but when I do:

```
json.loads(request.body)
```

I am getting:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `json.dumps` takes a python dictionary/JSON object and the counter function, `json.loads` takes a json string. You can't do `dumps/loads` on a form encoded string. Whoever is making this http request, they can do JSON.stringify, make a valid json string, set their `Content-type`, header as `application/json` and send it

Comment: @MadhavanKumar sorry, wrong function name, I meant loads()

Comment: @doniyor But it's still not valid JSON. You need to make it a JSON format to load it as a JSON object.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan how to do that?

Comment: `'{"event": "project.status.update", "project_id": "807276", "project_status_code": "in_progress"}'`

Comment: @doniyor I'm not very familiar with Django, is the format of `request.body` always `"key=value&key=value&key=value"`?

Comment: Why are you trying to load this as JSON? It's a standard POST, which you can get as a querydict from `request.POST`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman right, but in the API docs i am working with, they say i need to expect for json data in callback, but the real data isnot json, i didnot know that this data is plain post body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.body` contains form-encoded data, not json-encoded data. This is automatically decoded to a Python dict in `request.POST`. So, instead of using `request.body` directly with `json.loads`, you should be using `request.POST`.

Answer (score 0):

`json.dumps` takes a python dictionary/JSON object and the counter function, `json.loads` takes a json string.

You can't do dumps/loads on a form encoded string.

Whoever is making this http request, they can do `JSON.stringify`, make a valid json string out of form data object, set their `Content-type`, header as `application/json` and send it

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON string must be like the below one in order to use `json.loads()`

```
'{
    "event": "project.status.update", 
    "project_id": "807276", 
    "project_status_code": "in_progress"
}'
```

Comment: Though this technically answers the question it's not a practical solution that allows the asker to fix the problem. Manually changing this instance of a string into a dictionary isn't a solution that will work next time.