# Django: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'PUT'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

```
def my_view(request, someid=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # do stuff
        return HttpResponse({})

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        print request.body
        print request.PUT

        print json.loads(request.body)

        return HttpResponse({})
```

this is my view and I'm making a PUT request (using Postman-an api simulator) 
`x-www-form-urlencode`

when I do `request.body` it prints all data I'm sending in the form of `a=1&b=2&c=3`. so when I do `json.loads(request.body)`, it raises value error, `no json object could be decoded`. thats understandable. json.loads needs a json data.

but when I print `request.PUT` it says `object has no attribute PUT`. we generally do `request.GET` or `request.POST`, right? but why not 'PUT'?.

so I have two questions-

1) how do I convert this `request.body` format into python dictionary?

2  why I'm not able to print request.PUT

I have even tried `request.POST` in the 'PUT' block but its empty.

similar question has been asked here
[ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded - Django request.body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984481/valueerror-no-json-object-could-be-decoded-django-request-body)

but its not exactly same this might be having issue in POST block.

apart from this, I need request.body, I don’t want to manually extract field like

```
put = QueryDict(request.body)
description = put.get('description')
...
```

there are many fields so i cant do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
from django.http import QueryDict
qd = QueryDict(request.body)
put_dict = {k: v[0] if len(v)==1 else v for k, v in qd.lists()}
```

.
    now you can directly update an object by `**put_dict`

OR

one liner

```
put_dict = {k: v[0] if len(v)==1 else v for k, v in QueryDict(request.body).lists()}
```